# Changing which View is next to show in ViewFlipper

Tags: android, android-view

What I'm trying to accomplish is to have a main screen with three buttons, and depending on which button you press the corresponding view slides in from the right hand side. I have used `ViewFlipper` and using `ViewFlipper.showNext()` I am able to slide in the next View. I would like to be able to change which View is next in line so that I can have buttons corresponding to views.

I have tried to use `ViewFlipper.add()` and `ViewFlipper.remove()` to achieve this but to no avail. Could somebody tell me where I'm going wrong? Thanks in advance.

Below is my code for my `main.xml`, and each View is a separate layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ViewFlipper xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/flipper"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<include
    android:id="@+id/main"
    layout="@layout/first_view" />

//Do I need these below?
<include
    android:id="@+id/first"
    layout="@layout/more_info_1" />

<include
    android:id="@+id/second"
    layout="@layout/more_info_2" />

<include
    android:id="@+id/third"
    layout="@layout/more_info_3" />

</ViewFlipper>
```

And here is my `onCreate()` method:

```
flipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.flipper);
    Button moreInfo1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.moreinfobutton1);
    Button moreInfo2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.moreinfobutton2);
    Button moreInfo3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.moreinfobutton3);
    Button backButton1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.backbutton1);
    Button backButton2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.backbutton2);
    Button backButton3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.backbutton3);

    moreInfo1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            flipper.setInAnimation(inFromRightAnimation());
            flipper.setOutAnimation(outToLeftAnimation());
            flipper.showNext();
            }
        });

    moreInfo2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            flipper.setInAnimation(inFromRightAnimation());
            flipper.setOutAnimation(outToLeftAnimation());

            //What to put here to change the next View to something else?
            flipper.showNext();
            }
        });

    moreInfo3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            flipper.setInAnimation(inFromRightAnimation());
            flipper.setOutAnimation(outToLeftAnimation());
            flipper.showNext();
            }
        });

    backButton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View view) {
             flipper.setInAnimation(inFromLeftAnimation());
             flipper.setOutAnimation(outToRightAnimation());
             flipper.showPrevious();      
         }
     });

    backButton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View view) {
             flipper.setInAnimation(inFromLeftAnimation());
             flipper.setOutAnimation(outToRightAnimation());
             flipper.showPrevious();      
         }
     });

    backButton3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View view) {
             flipper.setInAnimation(inFromLeftAnimation());
             flipper.setOutAnimation(outToRightAnimation());
             flipper.showPrevious();      
         }
     });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using these methods of `ViewFlipper`:

```
public void removeViewAt (int index)
public void addView (View child, int index, ViewGroup.LayoutParams params)
```

This should allow you to remove a certain view you don't need anymore and add another one.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to do it with those methods by just having the initial one in my xml, and adding the View I wanted each time, removing it afterwards